# float division in unityscript

Tags: floating-point, unity-game-engine, unityscript

Why does this code give 536870912 as output and not 536870911.5?

```
var z : double = 1073741823.0 / 2.0;
Debug.Log(z.ToString("F15"));
```

And how can I get it to output 536870911.5?
This seems odd to me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get it with the below using C#:

```
double test = 1073741823.0d / 2.0d; // = 536870911.5
Debug.Log(test);
```

---

And in UnityScript, you just need to add the d's

```
var test : double = 1073741823.0d / 2.0d; // = 536870911.5
Debug.Log(test);
```

---

Without the double notation, UnityScript is parsing the numbers as some other type. (Most likely an int)

The below does NOT work because the interpreter isn't casting them correctly:

```
var test : double = 1073741823.0 / 2.0; // = 536870912
Debug.Log(test);
```

Looks to me like it's reading: **double = int / int;**

---

Very interesting. This is another reason why I encourage developers to move to C#.

Comment: It looks more like 32-bit floating point than integer. Most integer divisions truncate, so 1073741823/2 would be 536870911, not 536870912. Most floating-point implementations round by default, and, in IEEE-754 32-bit binary floating point, 1073741823 rounds to 1073741824.